# Apple Watch Simulator not Vertically Scrolling

Tags: scroll, apple-watch

I created a basic table on my Apple Watch App, with a table row element in a group element which gets populated programatically by iterating over a simple array. The table displays in the simulator, but I cannot get it to scroll vertically through all the table entries. Have I missed something or does the simulator not support this action?

Followed the tutorial here http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-create-table/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your table contained in a `WKInterfaceGroup`, by any chance? That would prevent proper scrolling.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something silly like this.