# Can't get scroll view to work on my WatchOS

Tags: swift, xcode, watch

I can't get pickerview scrollview to work on watchOS

I'm using "Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)"

step:1

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var picker: WKInterfacePicker!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.

        let item1 = WKPickerItem()
        item1.title = "1"

        let item2 = WKPickerItem()
        item2.title = "2"

        let item3 = WKPickerItem()
        item3.title = "3"

        let item4 = WKPickerItem()
        item4.title = "4"

        let itemsArray = [item1, item2, item3, item4]

        picker.setItems(itemsArray)


        picker.setEnabled(true)
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }
}
```

My problem is it does not scrolling in WatchOS simulator

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?: [Apple Watch Simulator not Vertically Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640985/apple-watch-simulator-not-vertically-scrolling)

Also, the version you mention at the top of your post, I assume it is Xcode?  Have you tried to use the mouse or trackpad to scroll by clicking on the watch simulator and then scrolling like you would do on the Mac?

Comment: @Cobra It's not working for me too.
Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Ali123, I believe it works, yes.  Maybe you can post a new question, with version of Xcode, and what you are doing?  Are you also having trouble with pickerview on the simulator?

Comment: @Cobra
Now I start doubting the expected behavior of the WKInterfacePicker. Is the picker suppose to interact to the touch or just the crown? For me, I used Xamarin.iOS and the picker is not responding to touches.

Comment: Oh, maybe that was the OP problem as well.  Have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacepicker .  The crown is used to scroll the picker.  You can touch on the item to select it, then use the crown to scroll.  Then touch it again so that it sends a tapped notification for your code to act on (docs basically say all that as well.)  No indication it supports scroll by finger.

Comment: As a side note, I noticed that Apple changed the scrolling number views (in the Custom timer setup) used for their default timer app on the Watch.  Those views do support scrolling with touch or the crown.  Maybe 4.3x versions of watchOS support both now.  The docs don't say that though.